# How to properly install the libmysql.dll on Windows?

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

I'm getting the following error message when I try to run an application that connects to a MySQL database instance:

"[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL]-314. Cannot load vendor library [libmysql.dll or libmysqld.dll]. Hint check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has x86 bitness.".

The error persists even with the libmysql.dll file on the same directory of the application executable.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond to install the MySQL Connector/C to get the libmysql.dll, it is necessary to install the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 too.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy libmysql.dll into the same folder of the application, or add the path to libmysql.dll into Path variable of system.

Comment: All is described in [the reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC)). And to be honest, I would avoid that `PATH` thing. It's 21st century ;-)

Comment: I have followed this reference without success. After some time, I have figure out about the Visual Studio dependency. The most recent MySQL Connector/C installer does not install this dependency.